# Tips for figuring out change of variables $\int_{0}^{8} \int_{y^{1/3}}^{2} \sqrt{1+x^4} dx dy$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm not seeing any obvious change of variables for the following integral:

$$\int_{0}^{8} \int_{y^{1/3}}^{2} \sqrt{1+x^4} dx dy$$

Comment: Did you mean for the bounds of the inner integral to be $y^{1/3} \le x \le 2$? Also, the integrand is complex when $x > 1$. You probably should double check to make sure you have the correct problem.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Thanks!  I corrected the typo

Comment: $1$ should, most likely, be $16$ and the trick is to change the order of integration, after which the change of variable required for finding the resulting 1-dimensional integral will become pretty obvious

Comment: @fedja Wow I gave up too soon.  Thanks

Comment: @fedja I just realized I had minus instead of plus.  Long day lol

Comment: @JimmyK4542 I just realized I had minus instead of plus.  Long day lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change order of integration:
$\int_{0}^{8} \int_{y^{1/3}}^{2} \sqrt{1+x^4} dx dy = \int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{x^3} \sqrt{1+x^4} dy dx = \int_{0}^{2} x^3\sqrt{1+x^4} dx = \frac{1}{4}\frac{2}{3} (1+x^4)^{3/2}\Big|_0^2 = \frac{1}{6}(17\sqrt{17}-1)$